# R package: checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ERROR

Tags: r, rstudio, cran, r-package

I am kind of new in package development in R and I am not sure if this is a common error...

I am developing a new package, using RStudio Version 0.99.491 on a Mac with OS X El Capitan [platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)].

When I "build and reload the package, everything is working fine but when I check the package, I get 1 error with the DESCRIPTION meta-information. It doesn't provide any meaningful details and I'm not sure what does this mean:

```
Status: 1 ERROR
checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... ERROR

See

'/Users/Ladislas/Desktop/itER.Rcheck/00check.log'
for details.

R CMD check results
1 error  | 0 warnings | 0 notes
```

Here is the log file :

```
* using log directory '/Users/Ladislas/Desktop/itER.Rcheck'
* using R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
* using platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
* using session charset: ASCII
* using options '--no-manual --as-cran'
* checking for file 'itER/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* this is package 'itER' version '0.0.0.9000'
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for executable files ... OK
* checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
* checking for portable file names ... OK
* checking for sufficient/correct file permissions ... OK
* checking whether package 'itER' can be installed ... OK
* checking installed package size ... OK
* checking package directory ... OK
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... ERROR
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
* DONE
Status: 1 ERROR
```

and my DESCRIPTION file:

```
Package: itER
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Title: Some Nice functions.
Date: 2016-09-28
Authors@R: person("Ladislas", "Nalborczyk", email = "ladislas.nalborczyk@gmail.com", role = c("aut", "cre") )
Description: some description.
License: MIT + file LICENSE
LazyData: yes
RoxygenNote: 5.0.1
Imports: AICcmodavg, lme4, plyr
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe try adding an explicit line with `Encoding: UTF-8` ?

Comment: Also ... anything weird with your R version?  The `During startup` is strange.

Comment: Your `Title` field ends in a period. That's not legal. You can get better diagnostic checks with `devtools::check()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Adding the Encoding line did not solve my problem but upgrading R to the most recent version did.

Comment: However, I am now getting a new warning :
`* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... WARNING
Invalid license file pointers: LICENSE`